# Click all specific text in a web page script

Tags: javascript

So I am an approver of a specific intranet web site in our company.

and everyday I have a lot of items to approve just by clicking on the 'Approve' button.

How can I create a script so that all 'Approve' button will be clicked right away.

Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you access the source code?

Comment: Does clicking the approve button reload the page in any way, or is it asynchronous?  If it's not an asynchronous process, there may be issues with just clicking every Approve button either at the same time or very quickly...

Comment: *Aside from the technical challenge, be careful here: if the point of your job is to visually verify that each item is appropriate before clicking 'approve'... Then, if you automatically approve everything and some wrong items are approved, you may be looking for another job as well as a technical solution.*

Comment: This sounds like a request for code to help you avoid doing your job. That seems like a really bad idea. Anyway, that aside, you need to show us some representative html to give us an idea of what you have to work with.

Comment: If you question is: "How can I automate clicking buttons on a company web page from my own computer" then please amend your question to make that point clear. *(By the way, that is an excellent technical question/challenge -- I haven't done it myself, but the solution may involve one or more of the following topics: screen scraping, web bots, or cURL. You might also check out autohotkey, autoIT or WinBatch.)*

Comment: @gibberish Or as was mentioned above, to add to your list, a small bit of javascript in a bookmarklet

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thanks James. And could greaseMonkey help here also? (Again, I haven't done this and have often wondered about this same thing)

Comment: @gibberish Potentially, yes - though I've not looked at it myself before either :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thanks James. BTW, you've got some good other answers - I had a quick scan. Well done.

Comment: @gibberish cheers - trying to start paying back a little!